# Express: problem using async await in a controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

I don't know whats happen here, I'm just using async await:

```
const Employee = require('../models/employee');

const employeeCtrl = {};

employeeCtrl.getEmployees = async (req, res) => {
  const employees = await Employee.find();
  res.json(employees);
}

employeeCtrl.createEmployee = async (req,res) => {
  const employee = new Employee(req.body)
  console.log(employee);
  await employee.save();
  res.json('recivied');
}

employeeCtrl.getEmployee = function() {

}

employeeCtrl.editEmployee = function() {

}

employeeCtrl.deleteEmployee = function() {

}

module.exports = employeeCtrl;
```

this return an error:

> TypeError: Employee.find is not a function
>       at employeeCtrl.getEmployees (D:\curso\server\controllers\employee.controller.js:6:31)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (D:\curso\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at jsonParser (D:\curso\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:110:7)

Why is find not a function?

This is the model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  position: {type: String, required: true},
  office: {type: String, required: true},
  salary: {type: Number, required: true}
})

mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema);
```

Comment: Probably because `Employee` in `../models/employee` doesn't have such a method.

Comment: @blockhead I added the file ../models/employee can you check please?

Comment: You are not exporting your model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not exporting anything from your model. You need to export it like so:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  position: {type: String, required: true},
  office: {type: String, required: true},
  salary: {type: Number, required: true}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema);
```

Additionally, `.find()` does not return a `Promise`. It returns a `Query` object as stated in the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

You need to chain it with `.exec()` which returns a `Promise`: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec

```
employeeCtrl.getEmployees = async (req, res) => {
  const employees = await Employee.find().exec();
  res.json(employees);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your are not exporting the schema you just made.

Try this

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema);
```

Instead of just this

```
mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code sample, it doesn't appear you're exporting the model. Perhaps try this in `models/Employee`:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema);
```